# cmb2 don't show date in proper format

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

My Custom Meta Box 2 plugin don't show date in proper format in the frontend.Below is the code i used :

```
function evoice_custom_metabox(array $evoice_meta){

$prefix = '_cmb2_';

$evoice_meta[] = array(
        'id' => 'meta_courses',
        'title' => 'Add The custom Filelds Below',
        'object_types' => array('courses' , 'post'),
        'fields' => array(
                array(
                        'name' => 'Date',
                        'type' => 'text_date_timestamp',
                        'id'   => 'courses_date'
                    ),

            )
    );


  return $evoice_meta;
}

add_filter('cmb2_meta_boxes', 'evoice_custom_metabox');
```

and I the index.php i used in the loop is:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'courses_date', true); ?>
```

But i am getting :`1428624000` though i selected : 04/10/2015 from admin panel

Is there any problem i am doing?Other fields are working properly

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to format the date. Try the following

```
<?php echo date("d.m.Y", get_post_meta($post->ID, 'courses_date', true)); ?>
```